# Eclipse from Windows to Mac

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, macos

I installed "Eclipse Juno" on Windows 7, made an application and uploaded it on Google Play.

Now, I cant find "Eclipse Juno" to download/install on Mac to make an Android Application, does anyone know? Is there another Eclipse but Juno?

Thanks

Comment: Another thing, https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/sr2 a Juno, but .... I dont know

Comment: Eclipse is no longer supported by Google for Android.  You can make it work, but I'd seriously consider moving to Android Studio.

Comment: Also, Juno is no longer the most recent version.  It looks like Neon is.  You'd need to find a repository of old versions to get Juno, at the least I'd upgrade to Neon.